# Webview does not scroll vertically inside ViewPager

Tags: android, webview, android-pageradapter

We are trying to load html data into webview inside viewpager using PagerAdapter. So, there are multiple pages with webview in viewpager. All pages with webview loads data perfectly. But, only first webview scrolls vertically. Other webviews are not vertically scrollable.
Please, help us to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T12-Book/EmPubLite), part of a series of tutorials in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), that demonstrates a `ViewPager` with scrollable `WebView` widgets as the pages.

Comment: Have you set the orientation of Webview in xml

Comment: thank you sir @commonsware.

Comment: No. @Awadesh. Not able to set orientation in xml. Tried to set vertically scrollabar method i.e. webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); programmatically. But, it is not working.

Comment: Finally, we found the issue. It was of viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new FlipHorizontalTransformer()); After removing this flipping animation, webviews vertical scrolling working perfectly.

Comment: We are getting another problem. On Screen Orientation change i.e. in Landcape mode, the fragment calls onDestroyView() method and not able to display any data. And again after screen orientation change i.e. in portrait mode, it's working properly. Please, help us to find solution on this. Webview should display data in landscape mode also.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this problem. The solution for my was change the library appcompat and support to a downgrade version. I currently use this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Instead of 23.1.0 that block the scroll on my webviews.

Comment: We are getting another problem. On Screen Orientation change i.e. in Landcape mode, the fragment calls onDestroyView() method and not able to display any data. And again after screen orientation change i.e. in portrait mode, it's working properly. Please, help us to find solution on this. Webview should display data in landscape mode also.

Comment: You can use **setRetainInstanceState(true)** in your fragment. It will not be destroyed and charged again in the orientation change.

Comment: We already used it in the fragment. Still, it does not retain data in webview of fragment. Only works perfectly in portrait mode orientation. I have refered @commonsware [sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T12-Book/EmPubLite) that is of his part of series of tutorials.